# top property in CSS doesn't work with Internet Explorer 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have some form with radio and checkboxes.

It should to be like this:

[image: http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/7672/screenshot1hm.png]

The CSS:

```
.span-al-top
{
    position:relative;
    top:-7px;

}

.span-al-bottom
{
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label>Radio</label>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="uno" class="radio-margin"><span class="span-al-bottom">uno</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="due" class="radio-margin"><span class="span-al-bottom">due</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="tres" class="radio-margin"><span class="span-al-bottom">tres</span>
<br />
<label>Checkbox</label>
 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">one</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">two</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">three</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">four</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">five</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="checkbox-margin"><span class="span-al-top">six</span>
```

It works, but it doesn't work with Internet Explorer 6. In Explorer 6 I have this:

[image: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3822/screenshot12y.png]

Any idea how I fix it?

Comment: I won't even comment on IE 6.  [Does your HTML pass validation?](http://validator.w3.org/)  If not, you will have nothing but problems with all versions of IE and probably with other browsers too.

Comment: the fonts are different between the two screenshots, but your code doesn't mention the font at all. In the IE6 screenshot, the font is bigger and pushes everything out of line. Somewhere along the line, you're setting the font in a way that IE6 doesn't like, but you haven't shown us the relevant code. But I guess the real question is why the heck are you still working with IE6? Your company's managers must be completely insane.

Comment: @Sparky Yes it pass validation.

Comment: @Spudley you can't even imagine how i'mm sick of ie.. But anyway I do what they ask.. The font doesnt matter :) What i tryed to do was in radio the text in span is under the radiobutton and in the checkbox the text in span needs to be over the checkbox

Comment: @RaShe - I know it's off topic, but my advice: start looking for a new job. If you're stuck working on IE6, your skillset is rapidly becoming obsolete. If you stay where you are and they don't upgrade, you'll be unemployable anywhere else within a year or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved.. I just needed to add the code:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to both span styles.